# php concatenate string with html and css

Tags: php, html, css, concatenation

I have this php code where I wanted to concatenate:

```
return '<div class="height-shortcode" style="height:"'.$myHeight.'">'.$content.'</div>';
```

my resulting html should look something like this:

```
<div class="height-shortcode" style="height:10px">Hello World!!</div>
```

however I can't get rid of the extra double quotes around it:

```
<div class="height-shortcode" style="height:"10px">Hello World!!</div>
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You added one extra double qoute

```
return '<div class="height-shortcode" style="height:'.$myHeight.';">'.$content.'</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding one extra quote in height `"`.Its obvious that this will print one more quote `""` Your code should look like this

```
return '<div class="height-shortcode" style="height:'.$myHeight.'">'.$content.'</div>';
```

Hope this helps you